# Jobs aren't performed. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-activejob

I want to write test in order to check if jobs are performed. It looks as below:

## test/jobs/send_remember_email_job_test.rb

```
test "remember method was sent" do

  assert_performed_jobs 0

  assert_enqueued_jobs 1 do
    SendRememberEmailJob.perform_later('some@mail.com', 0)
  end

  assert_performed_jobs 1

end
```

## app/jobs/send_remember_email_job.rb

```
class SendRememberEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(email,time, task)
    UserMailer.delay(run_at:time.hours.from_now).remember_mail(email,task)
  end
end
```

When I run test, I always get 1 failure:

```
1 jobs expected, but 0 was performed.
Expected: 1
Actual: 0
```

I don't know if it helps, but I use **delayed_job**. Thank's in advance

Comment: Delayed jobs writes to db into `delayed_jobs` table that has `last_error` column. Look its value and post it here if it will not help you.

Comment: Check last_error column? How I suppose to do that when rails doesn't store test variables in database. In development everything works fine, but here tests fails. Any other idea?

Comment: Did you try change `SendRememberEmailJob.perform_later('some@mail.com', 0)` to `SendRememberEmailJob.perform_now('some@mail.com', 0)`?

Comment: Yes...it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be happening because delayed_jobs run is jobs in a background process by default so your test will not wait for it to finish the test fail.
Try to disable DelayedJobs so the jobs will run in real time.

You can do that with:

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it... and in addition my other test to check enqueued jobs fails.